# Angluar get Method being called from html causes infinite reload loop

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Im currently working on a project, that requires me to fill a dynamic number of buttons with links to douments to open them.

```
<tr *ngFor="let competence of competences; let i = index">{{competence.name.de}}
  <td *ngFor="let competenceLevel of levels; let j = index">
    <button type="button" *ngFor="let learnRecommendation of getLearnRecommendationsByIndex(i,j)" (click)="openDialog(learnRecommendation)">{{learnRecommendation.title | translateText}}</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This correctly fills the table with buttons and diplays the correct name, however no Events that I try to add to the buttons work. I need (click) but have tried things like (onload) for testing and these also dont work.
I eventually noticed, that all the buttons keep getting reloaded infinitely. A friend told me, that he thinks it could be connected to the get method im using, but I dont see how. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the code of the 2 methods "getLearnRecommendationsByIndex" and "openDialog"

Comment: I've created a quick reproduction of your issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kty4vl) and it seems to be working...

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with the angular change detection.

Angular cannot detect whether the result of `getLearnRecommendationsByIndexis` changed until it runs the `getLearnRecommendationsByIndexfunction`.

That's why it need to execute it in every change detection cycle, in order to get the returned value and make sure that nothing has been changed.

The same thing is true if you use a getter or a setter. This is especially troublesome when you the function returns a collection from https calls, as the call will occur once every cycle making the application unresponsive.

What's worse? Even if the returned values are the same, if they are new objects (as an observable would return), angular asumes that there are changes and the dom is rebuilt.

To avoid this, you can use the `OnPush` change detection strategy

Example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-selector',
  templateUrl: 'someurl' ,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class OnPushDetComponent { 

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {

  }

  runChangeDetection() {
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

Bear in mind that your view will only be updated when you run the ChangeDetection and not automatically.

Another thing you can do, is to capture the return values to an array and use that array on your view.